# How do I improve performance for page loading on mobile?

Tags: ios, ruby-on-rails, web

I'm doing rails development locally (i.e. WEBrick 1.3.1). To test mobile, I put my iPhone 4s (iOS 8.1) on the same local network and load from the appropriate IP address.

**It's really slow.**

I watch the console and I can't figure out what the bottleneck is. I don't get the same behavior when I'm running the desktop browser locally. Of course, there's supposed to be some latency since the packets have to go over the wire, but it's unbelievably slow, on the order of more than 7 seconds. Sometimes not all the resources are loaded.

How can I improve load times for iOS/iPhone/mobile? Has anyone else run into this? For example, I thought perhaps it might be because we're loading fonts. Do local fonts (i.e. fonts that are on the system already) get optimized for rendering? This would explain some of the slow-down since we send a custom font.

Answer (score 0):

if you have launched it online, are sure the perforamnce issues is not from your hosting provider. if you are on a shared server, may be your server are heavily overloads with contents from other users. when i first launched my application built with phonegap, i experience the same issues of server sluggishness. i have to move to another hosting server and perhaps my apps becomes super fast.